# Is derivation based Math a good way to teach my 5 years old daughter addition?

Tags: axioms-foundations

I love deriving formulas. I am pretty good at Math. Maybe because I have a little asperger syndrome.

Most people don't learn Math that way. Why not?

I recently taught peano axioms to my daughter. She seems to be able to grasp it a little, then I'll teach the basic again.

I just want Math to be very easy for her like it is for me.

Comment: $x+(y+1)=(x+y)+1$ and $x=1 \vee \exists y.x=y+1$?  I can imagine Peano-inspired discussions with a five-year old, but if she doesn't understand equations and variables and parentheses then I wouldn't say she understands the Peano axioms.

Comment: **One question here:** Why don't people learn mathematics "that way" (by "deriving formulas"?) **Another question here:** "Is peano axiom a good way to teach my 5 years old daughter addition?" These are two different questions, and I don't think either is a good fit without further clarification, i.e., I'm not sure what is being asked.

Comment: @Benjamin Dickman: Regarding *I'm not sure what is being asked*, what I find interesting is that I agree with you (I don't know what "taught peano axioms" means at this level), but I also know right away (without thinking) what my answer is (definitely NO).

Comment: Rolled back the edit: Unclear why it should have additional tags added since the OP has not made any effort to clarify the intended question.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Fair enough

Answer (score -5):

My mother used to be a primary school teacher (now retired). And one of the things she complained a lot about was parents teaching children the subjects *before* they came up at school, and specially parents that used *different* approaches than those taught. Children used to do things "some other way" get confused, and are often a distraction on the other pupils.

Please don't do this. Find out what she sees at school, and how, and help her understand that. See what other interests she has (perhaps plants or animals in the garden? going to the zoo and learning more about exotic animals? palenteology, and learning about the animals which used to live where you are?) and see to share that with her (as long as it doesn't interfere with what is done at school, it should be fine).

[Yes, I'm assuming she attends school, or will do so soon(ish). At home tutoring is another kettle of fish...]

Comment: To me this answer reflects an attitude that teachers are meant to teach a cookbook of specific methods, and not how to think about problems.  Different ways of approaching the problem should add richness to the class discussion, not be treated as a distraction.  Although it may be true that many teachers will consider it a 'bad thing' for a student to be exposed to different approaches to the material before they attend school, I strongly disagree.  And it is certainly the parent's right and responsibility to supplement what is/will be taught in schools, especially if it is limited to recipes.

Comment: @PurpleVermont, as long as schools work like they do, *I* alone won't be able to change that. My daughter had the luck to be in a school that (apart from the mandated drill curriculum) did emphasize problem solving, estimating, and other activities, both in class and as extra activities (one week they had a fish bowl full of candies, to be distributed in the class which got the closest estimate on their number, with some explanation of the estimate).

Comment: No, neither of us can change the way schools work, but that doesn't mean we have to kowtow to them and decline to teach our kids interesting things that might not be the same as what they will see at school.  Yes, we will have to also teach our kids to understand that there are multiple approaches, and they may see a different one at school, and if you get an inflexible teacher, you may have to teach "doing it the teacher's way" as a peace-keeping skill.  But I hate the idea of just not teaching things because school will do it differently.

Comment: One of the key things I want to teach students is that mathematical operations are real structures that come up through out the universe and can be computed in many ways. A student who knows a different way to add, multiply or differentiate should be an opportunity to teach why the methods give the same answer, not a problem.

Comment: +1, Are we downvoting this answer because it is not useful, or because we disagree with it?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer, I do agree. But *don't* try doing that before they are able to appreciate the difference.

Comment: @ChrisCunningham, I believe we need more primary school teachers here... I'm very much opposed to mere drill, and would very much prefer more problem-solving oriented education at all levels. But I still stand by my answer, doing what I criticize isn't helpful at all *in that age range*.

Comment: I do not think age matters at all. Kids with different IQ understand things differently.

Comment: @vonbrand -- regarding [this comment](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/3823/is-derivation-based-math-a-good-way-to-teach-my-5-years-old-daughter-addition#comment7546_3826), maybe edit your answer to allow some of the downvoters (like me!) to remove their downvotes.....depending on the nature of the edit, some may even switch to an upvote!

Comment: I downvoted, then realized that @ChrisCunningham was correct....now feel bad about the downvote, and would remove it if I could....

Comment: @Tutor, I can't see any way to accomodate Cris Cunningham's comment. And even with the downvotes, I stand behind what I say. Children are vulnerable, being made fun of in school because your dad teaches you different can be damaging.

Comment: @vonbrand I think maybe it was unclear: what I meant was that I suspected people were downvoting your answer for poor reasons.